# What do they mean by "ambient condition"?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm reading a technical lab report which study the effect of light and temperature on a silicon wafer. However i'm a bit confused if ambient condition in this case means.

> Task 3, Investigate the influence of ambient conditions on the diode characteristics
>   In this task both the silicon wafer and the SiC piece should be utilized. Perform reverse IV
>   sweeps in dark and under illumination. (For the silicon wafer these measurements could be
>   combined with Task 1). Perform measurements at room temperature and at least one selected
>   elevated temperature, focus on the forward characteristics.

- Is this means the effect of light on a piece of silicon?
- or is it the effect of temperature?
- or is it means the effect of both light and temperature on a piece of silicon?

Comment: Please provide the whole sentence or a paragraph. It's always hard to tell the exact meaning without context.

Comment: [**Ambient conditions**](https://www.grundfos.com/service-support/encyclopedia-search/ambient-condition.html) *typically include temperature, humidity and air pressure.* You haven't given the exact full context, but in a "technical lab report" it probably means those three (and possibly other) aspects of the environment are ***typical*** (not especially dark, humid, hot, noisy, windy, whatever). Effectively, ***ambient = surrounding*** environment, as shared by technicians *and* the thing being tested (which isn't hermetically sealed from the overall environment of the testing procedure).

Comment: **Ambient** probably means the laboratory conditions, before applying artificial conditions to the test sample. The test would make a study of the effect of varying both temperature and light in a controlled way.

Comment: The question edit includes "Perform measurements at room temperature". This is the ambient condition.

Answer (score 1):

**Ambient conditions** are the general environmental conditions in an area. It is related to the word *ambience*. Thus it would certainly include temperature, and may include light if that's a particularly relevant environmental condition. It could also be humidity, air pressure, air movement, presence of dust, and so on.